# How can I override Core Symfony2 Classes?

Tags: symfony

I want to override a core Symfony2 Class.

Specifically I want to override  vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/TemplateReference.php, the TemplateReference so I can alter locations where it finds templates.. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: For example.. I want to auto detect mobile devices, and if the user is coming from a mobile device i'd like to see if the equivalent template file is at views/mobile/ instead of /views/ ..  The exact file I mentioned holds the class that finds the path location for twig templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not do this, unless you know exactly what you're doing, and you're 100% sure you won't break something ...

If you're using the Symfony 2.0 ClassLoader component:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony' => array(
        __DIR__.'/../src/vendor/symfony/src',
        __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src',
        __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    ),
    ...
));
```

To do this with composer, this should work, edit your `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
         "": "src/",
         "Symfony": "src/vendor/symfony/src/"
    }
},
```

This tells the autoloader, that when it tries to load a class from the `Symfony` namespace, to first look in your `src/vendor/symfony/src`, then in `vendor/symfony/src` then in `vendor/bundles` ...

And then duplicate the file you want to edit there:

```
src/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/TemplateReference.php
```

Comment: Symfony relies on composers autoloading mechanism in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, but his question is tagged as 2.0 and not 2.1 :)

Comment: ehm ... Started the comment with "But 2.0 uses composer too", but I were wise enought to have a look at it first. You are completely right.

Comment: He's saying you'all have to do this differently using composer on 2.1, but this could be easily achievable.

Comment: How can I do this with 2.1? As I guess I should of mentioned 2.1 specifically, but I don't want to write a new question now just for that. :)

Comment: I'll have to test that out later on, thanks for the great examples!

Comment: So.. This works perfectly, however can I still extend the previous Core class using this method somehow?  I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override some classes defined as service (you can check on app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProejctContainer.xml), and override the service name on your parameter.ini.

BUT if the class it not defined like this, you can create your own "patch" you apply after a composer update.

Lot of people will say its dirty to edit core classes, but if you want good performance, its often the only solution to achieve it ;-), its simple, fast & easy.

Other solutions are welcome ..

Comment: this answer got little bit hidden, more detailed info can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225839/how-to-overwrite-symfony2-core-frameworkbundle
btw touching core classes is bad, never do that