# How should I structure my application?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I understand that this question may be vague, I will try my best to explain my problem and hopefully can get lots of insights from the experienced and hopefully this will not be closed.

I'm writing a PHP web app framework based on Symfony 2's components and bundles, my question may not relate to that however. The framework is intended to be **open to 3rd party plugins**, these plugins will have their own config files (yaml) and the person who install these plugins should be able to **override these settings locally**.

I also have to make sure that each time the person perform the plugin upgrade operation, it should be easy to loop over the list of "upgrade patches" to upgrade the plugin's settings while still **retaining the local settings**.

I imagine I can have a local, app's specific plugins.yml file which store something like this:

```
pluginA:
  somesettings: value
  somesettings2: value2
```

This app's specific settings file will allow user to override any default settings. And then each plugin can contain an "upgrade" class that will contain all the patches for each version, the framework will identify the current installed path and will loop through each "upgrade patch" and perform actions until it reach the most current version.

Does this sound like a good option, or if there is something else I should look into? How do I have configuration settings that can be overridden can be upgraded easily? Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are looking to achieve something that actually core Symfony allows to do - i. e. to let other users override / implement custom parts of an already existing bundle.
If so, maybe this answer can give a good idea on how to achieve that using the ClassLoader Component (Symfony 2.0) or Composer (Symfony 2.1):

[How can I override Core Symfony2 Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464119/how-can-i-override-core-symfony2-classes)